# How do you create a custom page in Presta Shop?

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I have followed many tutorials, but they are either cryptic or they did not work, or they wanted you to use the terrible CMS block module which gives you limited control over the custom elements of a page.

So far:

1. I created a controller called ProgramsController.php and put it into `ps_root/controllers/front`

   ```
   class ProgramsControllerCore extends FrontController
   {
       public $php_self = 'programs';
       public function init()
       {
           parent::init();
       }

       public function initContent()
       {
           parent::initContent();
           $this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'programs.tpl');
       }
   }
   ```
2. I created a template called programs.tpl and put it into `ps_root/themes/mytheme/ folder`

I then use: `localhost/index.php?controller=programs` or I use the SEO and links builder to create a `localhost/programs` link, and I get an error: `Fatal error: Class 'ProgramsController' not found in ...\classes\controller\Controller.php on line 135`

But that's not right since the path ought to be a `../controllers/front` path, why is it looking in `../classes/controller`? I assume from all the tutorials that the dispatcher should know to hook my front controller to the correct template. Why is this not working?

Basic Question:
In PrestaShop 1.6 I just want to know how to create custom pages like: `http://myshop.com/mycustompage`

But that it also utilizes the existing header and footer.

Comment: delete `/cache/class_index.php` file and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For creating a new custom page you have to follow some steps:

you have to create a new folder in your modules folder of prestashop like

```
C:\wamp\www\prestashop\modules\your_module_name
```

Then you put your controller file in your module folder like:

```
C:\wamp\www\prestashop\modules\your_module_name\controller\front\your_file.php
```

And in that you code like:

```
class ProgramsControllerCore extends FrontController
{
    public $php_self = 'programs';
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
    }

    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();
        $this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'programs.tpl');
    }
}
```

Then you make a new folder views in your module like:

```
C:\wamp\www\prestashop\modules\your_module_name\views
```

Then in that you make another folder named template and in that another a folder named front like:

```
C:\wamp\www\prestashop\modules\your_module_name\views\templates

C:\wamp\www\prestashop\modules\your_module_name\views\templates\front
```

Then in that file you have to put your theme file Like

```
C:\wamp\www\prestashop\modules\your_module_name\views\templates\front\programs.tpl
```

and now render your file. I hope it would work.